# Crosstab Query in Access and/or SQL to accomplish table combination

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, crosstab

I have a survey (multi-criteria decision analysis) which dumps results into the following table named *CriteriaWeighting*:

```
User | Criteria1 | Criteria2 | ... | CriterX
--------------------------------------------
Name1|   n1w1    |    n1w2   | ... |   n1wX |
Name2|   n2w1    |    n2w2   | ... |   n2wX |
...
```

I would like to create a new table named *WeightinStats* with the following structure:

```
Criteria  |  Average  |  StDev  |  Var  |
-----------------------------------------
Criteria1 |  AVG(c1)  | StD(c1) | Var(c1)
Criteria2 |  AVG(c2)  | StD(c2) | Var(c2)
Criteria3 |  AVG(c3)  | StD(c3) | Var(c3)
...       |  ...      | ...     | ...
CriteriaX |  AVG(cX)  | StD(cX) | Var(cX)
```

where AVG(c1), StD(c1), Var(c1), etc. are the averages, std dev, and variance of all the various criteria weighting responses from above (n1w1, n1we, n1wX, etc.)

I have attempted implementing a crosstab query, but it never comes out right, so I am wondering if there is a way to forcibly create the desired table via SQL. I'm using MSAccess 2010.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, crosstab goes the other way. Had you started off with your desired structure (*WeightsinStats*) and needed your original structure (*CriteriaWeighting*), crosstab queries can achieve it. Of course with aggregation on the transformed end.

Reason being, [crosstab queries](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read--by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) transforms a record set in such a way that value items from one column become separate individual columns with corresponding numeric figures being aggregated: Sum(), Avg(), Count()...

However, going backwards you may need to do a UNION query. Do note: there is an Access SQL limit to the number of unions depending on complexity.

```
SELECT 'Criteria1'  As Criteria, Avg([Criteria1]), StDev([Criteria1]), Var([Criteria1])
FROM CriteriaWeighting
UNION 
SELECT 'Criteria2' As Criteria, Avg([Criteria2]), StDev([Criteria2]), Var([Criteria2])
FROM CriteriaWeighting
...
```

Should you have multiple criteria, you can build your union query dynamically with VBA:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim i As Integer, AllCriteriaCount As Integer

AllCriteriaCount = ??  'ENTIRE FULL COUNT OF CRITERIA HERE

Set db = Currentdb

' BUILD SQL STRING
For i = 1 To AllCriteriaCount

  If i = 1 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT 'Criteria1'  As Criteria, Avg([Criteria1]), StDev([Criteria1]), Var([Criteria1])" & _
             " FROM CriteriaWeighting"
  Else
    strSQL = strSQL & "UNION" & _
             " SELECT 'Criteria" & i & "' As Criteria, Avg([Criteria" & i & "]), StDev([Criteria" & i & "]), Var([Criteria" & i & "])" & _
             " FROM CriteriaWeighting"
  End If
Next i

' CREATE QUERY DEF (STORED QUERY)
Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("WeightinStatsquery", strSQL)

' MAKE-TABLE TO OUTPUT FINAL
db.Execute "SELECT * WeightinStatsquery INTO WeightinStats"

Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. I may just have to rework some elements of the db.